# Ember.Select with custom <select> plugin: how to bind the two?

Tags: ember.js

In our app, we replace the standard select by a jQuery plugin to be able to style the selects in CSS. I am trying to make it work with Ember but my solution is really dirty. Is there a proper way to do this?

I think the key issue is this kind of plugins need the HTML to be rendered in the page to update themselves. Yet, Ember bindings fire before the HTML is actually rendered in the page.

```
Ember.Select.reopen({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().selectBox(); // Create the jQuery plugin
    },
    valueChanged: function(){
        this.$().selectBox('value', this.get('value')); // Update the plugin value
    }.observes('value'),

    contentChanged: function(){
        this.set('value', "-10"); // Fake value, just to force the cache. Othwerwise it won't refresh if the previous value was also "0".
        this.set('value', "0"); // Default value for the new content.


        // Option 1: manually "re-create" the plugin using 'content' - it fails with:
        // Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.
        // And anyway it means 'content' needs to have a specific format which is not great.
        var contentAsJson = {};
        this.get('content').forEach(function(val){contentAsJson[val.get('id')] = val.get('displayName')});
        this.$().selectBox('destroy');
        this.$().selectBox();
        this.$().selectBox('options', contentAsJson);
        this.$().selectBox('value', this.get('value'));

        // Options 2: wait for the actual HTML to be rendered with a timer. It "works" but it is terrible I guess
        // to rely on a timer. 
        var self = this.$();
        setTimeout(function(){self.selectBox('refresh')}, 100);

    }.observes('content')

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you don't need to listen to value changer because the `selectBox` is already actively updating both the dom element and also the plugin itself. A simple trace in the `valueChanged` observer could tell you a lot of thing.

Based on your question I come out with this small snippet. In fact I think it's actually like your original method.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g8anT/6/)

```
Ember.Select.reopen({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.set('value', null);
        this.$().selectBox(); // Create the jQuery plugin
    },
    contentChanged: function() {
        //Ember.run.next is equivalent to setTimeout(fn,1);
        //We want to wait for contentChanged first to finish
        //then rerender selectBox.
        //To get the structure of key-value is too tedious so
        //just rerender it instead.
        Ember.run.next(this, function() {
            this.$().selectBox('refresh');
        });

        //Reset the selection value if you insist
        //this.set('value', null);
    }.observes('content')
});
```

I think it is ok to just `setTimeout` for it since you will need to wait for content to be rendered first. Refresh shouldn't be too heavy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lionel for your help! Unfortunately, it does not quite work, at least not entirely. The goal for me would be to have a "total" binding. By that I mean if you change the select itself programatically, it should change the selectBox as well. That's why - I think - you do need to observe the 'value'. I forked your jsFiddle, please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/4xxLA/.

Comment: Wrong link, sorry: http://jsfiddle.net/4xxLA/1/     (continued) If you change the select control itself (not the selectBox), you will see that the change is not applied to the selectBox. In addition, when you change the content for the select, the 'selected' field is not updated.